# how to execute net start on NODEJs?

Tags: node.js, windows, service, command-line

the `net start` command is used in the command prompt in windows to get a list of all running processes. How do i execute this from a NODEJs script. I have used the following code:

```
child = exec("net start", function (error, stdout, stderr){});
```

But I don't seem to be getting any output. What am I missing? Or if the output is being produced, how do I access it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [node-cmd](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-cmd) instead, this package executes the commands asynchronously and has callback feature too.

To Install,

```
npm install --save node-cmd
```

For e.g,

```
var cmd=require('node-cmd');

cmd.get(
    'net start',
    function(err, data, stderr){
        console.log('Output: ',data)
    }
);
```

Hope this helps!.

Comment: Thanks David, will try this. So can I use this package to execute any commands which can be executed on Command prompt?

Comment: Yes.. Absolutely! :-)

Comment: Thanks a lot David.

Comment: Great @Rai Glad that it has helped!

Comment: Hey David, just another query.. Can I use this for running cmd commands for windows command prompt as well?

Comment: Yes you can.. You can even execute batch files (`.bat`);

Answer (score 0):

Here's what i understood from your code, you're executing a command and not able to see the result because you're not using the callbacks to see the result

```js
exec("net start", function (error, stdout, stderr){});
```

You should use "stdout" to see the sucess result and "stderr" to see the failed result